# z-axis plotting of specific value pair for 2 column data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to do graph visualization of some specific pair `points(x,y)=(1,1)` of degree distribution and I want to plot these in the `z-axis` to extract valuable information . Is there any way to plot these kind of value pair from two column data file(which I have done 2D-plot in `gnuplot`)  in the z-axis ? I am new to `gnuplot` and found out that it needs three columns to plot the splot (`X`,`Y`,`Z` axis).

Any suggestion would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to plot as z-values: Some function of the x and y values? Or where does the additional data come from (as your data file has only 2 columns)?

Comment: I want to plot all the x=1, y=1 in the z-axis

Comment: So is points(x,y) a function and it is that value that gives z meaning? If so, can you type out the function points()?

Comment: @DanSp.  .....    Z= {(x==1)&&(y==1)} May be ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure that I got your question right but I assume that you have a data file with two columns that somehow represent a 2D object, in e.g. the form

```
1 1
0 0
1 1
1 1
0 0
...
```

and now want to plot these in a 2D grid where only the columns with 1 1 should be visible. That can easily be done with a ternary operator of the form

```
$1==1 && $2==1 ? 1 : 1/0
```

which sets all matching values to 1 and the others to 1/0 (which is invalid), you could also use 0 or any other.

If I got the style of your data right you will also need to wrap it around by the columns, e.g. if you assume 10 lines per x value the following commands

```
set pm3d map
plot 'data' using (int($0/10)):(int($0)%10):($1==1&&$2==1?1:1/0) with image
```

yielded this plot (with some 100 random line data):

[image: example plot]

I hope I got your question right.